# How to install build-essential?

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install G++ compiler in Ubuntu 13.10. It told me I needed to install the `build-essential` package.

I have tried the below code

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

It gives me this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package build-essential
```

Comment: did you find `build essential` package on synaptic and software-center?

Comment: what is build-essential good for?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. I solved it by entering 'sudo apt-get upgrade' after 'sudo apt-get update'.

Answer (score 81):

Type in the Terminal `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and then press key <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead of pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: Why does this solve the problem?

Comment: It helped me install ubuntu-restricted-extras .. thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me. Ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: @mafu Because with the tab you actually enter ...essentials not ...essential.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64. You have to enter TAB and then enter the ENTER key.

Comment: The OP and this answer uses the same `sudo apt-get install build-essential` command. So is correct the first comment of this answer.

Answer (score 47):

Enable *main repository* in Software & Updates.

Then run these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Note: `build-essential` includes the `gcc`/`g++` C and C++ compilers, respectively, and other build tools, for anyone wondering. See: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-g-the-c-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux.

Answer (score 9):

You have to enable the **main** repository in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
To accomplish this remove the `'#'` character in front of the following lines.

```
#deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
#deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main multiverse restricted universe
```

Save the file and execute
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, sometimes what happens is that if your first command fails due to some repo not responding or other network issues

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you may not be able to install build-essential. So always ensure that apt-get update completes successfully. Once update is commpleted, issue:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Now you should be able to install it successfully.

Comment: He has declared in the question that he gets error for it.

Comment: That's the reason I said that if there's an error, you have to run apt-get update again, to ensure that all repo's do respond. Sometimes repos don't respond due to network problem as that's the reason why I had an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install build essentials from software center
Open it up, and search for "build essential"

Answer (score 2):

These terminal commands should solve your problem:

First remove the Merge List by opening a terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T to launch) and run this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

or

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

these command lines are interchangable

the options used are -v verbose

```
-v, --verbose explain what is being done
```

and -f force

```
-f, --force ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

If you are ever unsure about a command line or the options being used always refer to the manual page for the command. These can be accessed on the internet by searching for man and the command for example man rm or you can access the same information by typing exactly the same command in the terminal for example man rm instructions for quitting the page will be at the bottom of the terminal like this

picture of man page options

Next, generate a new one by running a simple update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then do,

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Any drawback of removing all items in the "var/lib/apt/lists" folder?