# How do I install build-essential?

Tags: software-installation

when I run the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.then error occurred

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
```

I have inter-net connection free from proxy.

Comment: Post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` as well.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/398489/how-to-install-build-essential

Comment: no, I am running a operating system ubuntu 10.10.then what should I do.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.10 is an old, unsupported release so see this question: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)