# flash player plugin problem

Tags: chromium

I am trying to build pepperflash manually as it won't open from my software centre. Following these instructions:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/i-rinat/freshplayerplugin.git
cd freshplayerplugin
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

It goes grand till cmake .. then tells me the

```
"CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_NOTFOUND" was not found.
Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name."
```

Can't install chrome for some reason (maybe laptop is too old and small), am using chromium and firefox.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install build-essential?](/q/398489) if you really want to build freshplayerplugin or [this answer](/a/496797/175814) if you just want to install a pre-built package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install build-essential?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/398489/how-to-install-build-essential)

Answer (score 0):

Please try these commands in the terminal

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin`

or

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`