# Sudo make install not working in ubuntu

Tags: command-line, package-management, compiling

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 in the virtual machine.
The issue is that when I run the following command (`sudo make install`) in the terminal it shows me the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

I researched the problem solution online and when I came across one it said to perform the following:

1. Install missing dependencies
2. Check whether `build-essential` is installed
3. Run `./configure`

I did as instructed and found that the package `build-essential` was missing.

In a view to fix the error I referred to the following link:
[How to install build-essential?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398489/how-to-install-build-essential)

As mentioned I did the following things:
Ran the command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

When I ran the commands I found that `build-essential` was already installed and upgraded

When i run the command `./configure` it displays `no such file found` and when i try to run the same command: `sudo make install` it shows me the same error as before

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You are probably not running those commands from the directory where you stored the software that you want to install. Use `cd` to navigate to the proper directory.

Comment: Nobody can really answer this without knowing *what* you're trying to `make` and `install`

Comment: What software do you plan to compile? Are you sure that you really need to compile it? Did you checked http://packages.ubuntu.com to find the needed package in the repository of your Ubuntu version?

Comment: The title is misleading. The error message proves that the software is working.

Comment: Okay so I have an application in which I have to perform face detection on the raspberry pie for that I downloaded the servoblaster codes and to install those drivers I cd to the directory where i downloaded the fiiles. There as instructed I try to run the command  sudo make install amd it shows me the error

Comment: Related and helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source

Comment: Re-read @Jos' comment: Most likely you are simply in the wrong dir. Look for the makefile. If you can't find it, then you are in the wrong dir.

Comment: No i am in the same directory where i downloaded and extracted the files. Now when i Want to install the files i try to run the command and find an error

Comment: @ user535733: I downloaded the zip file from the GitHub. i read the readme file which really explains what each module does. So i unzipped the contents into the Document folder and then I cd into that folder. Then When i try to run the command sudo make install it gives me the error: no rule to make target install. stop. So i run the two commands as explained and it shows me what i explained that the required components are already installed. Then when i run ./configure why it shows no such file or directory

Comment: why not just tell us which file you're downloading?  If there's no Makefile nor configure file in your directory, of course they won't work.

Comment: https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster. This is the file I am downloading